# Why does mysql take very long time in insertion of rows?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a code where I need to be inserting into mysql table. I am using innodb storage engine. There could be concurrent clients inserting into the tableat times. My insert queries are sometimes taking as long as 50 secs to insert. I see very less lock times but execution time is quite large. Below are the times captured in slow query logs:

Query_time: 51.106628  Lock_time: 0.000043 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0

## Can anyone please explain where does mysql spends so much time inserting into table, where normally take time in order of milliseconds.

Below are the things I have narrowed down:
1. There can be no contention between concurrent inserts as mysql inserts can take gap locks but here my table is having auto-incremented primary key.
2. I have setting where flush to disk happens after every transaction commit, so it can not be the case where flush might be lagging causing insert to stall.

I tried keeping two column table where one column is auto-incremented PK and other is just a string column. I ran 100 threads to insert into the table and my slow query logs captured few inserts taing 10 sec where as normally inserts were taking few milliseconds, so it seems a generic issue of occasional slow inserts.

(from Comment)

The problem of occasional delay is happening with very simple structure as well. eg.

```
CREATE TABLE test_con_insert (
    id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    thread int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

insert into test_con_insert (thread) values(1);
```

slow query logs: # Query_time: 10.014465 Lock_time: 0.000035 Rows_sent: 0 Rows_examined: 0 insert into test_con_insert(thread) values (3833); 100 concurrent threads used to insert in this table.4 slow query captured.

Comment: do you have triggers ? can you send the output of 'show triggers' command ?

Comment: No, there are no triggers on this table. In fact I am not using any trigger for whole database at all.

Comment: Provide us your query and table structure please.

Comment: The problem of occasional delay is happening with very simple structure as well. eg. CREATE TABLE `test_con_insert` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `thread` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

insert into test_con_insert (thread) values(1);

slow query logs:

# Query_time: 10.014465  Lock_time: 0.000035 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
insert into test_con_insert(thread) values (3833);

100 concurrent threads used to insert in this table.4 slow query captured.

Comment: Is your server a virtual machine with nfs or kinda directories mapped? Do you have a virus scanner active that blocks IO? Please give us more information about your system.

Comment: looks like that there is nothing wrong with your query. can you post your my.cnf ? and check the mysql process performance. does it takes too much ram or cpu?

Comment: I have run this on linux as well as windows. I am seeing this thing on all platforms. This slowdown does not occur always, it occurs occasionally. Lets say when I am inserting through multiple concurrent threads. Its like two or three odd inserts that take much time out of 100.

Comment: Try to grab `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;` right after it happens.  Meanwhile, are the 100 connections inserting as fast as they can?  What version of MySQL?

Comment: Sure, I will get the innodb status. I am on mysql8.0.11. on the average the 100 inserts are quite fast. They take around few milliseconds to complete.

Comment: @RickJames
Innodb status has below info
-------
FILE I/O
-------
I/O thread 0 state: wait Windows aio (insert buffer thread)
I/O thread 1 state: wait Windows aio (log thread)
I/O thread 2 state: wait Windows aio (read thread)
I/O thread 3 state: wait Windows aio (read thread)
I/O thread 4 state: wait Windows aio (read thread)
I/O thread 5 state: wait Windows aio (read thread)
I/O thread 6 state: wait Windows aio (write thread)
I/O thread 7 state: wait Windows aio (write thread)
I/O thread 8 state: wait Windows aio (write thread)
I/O thread 9 state: wait Windows aio (write thread)